# Programmatically manipulate individual DupliFrame instances

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm trying to manipulate single lights in a light string by a python script (see [Animating running lights](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/94699/animating-running-lights) for more background info).

The string is created by using either an array+curve modifier or by using DupliFrames. Now I want to change some object attributes of the duplicates, ideally without applying the duplication, as I like to modify the curve afterwards.

Is there a way to access the duplicated object instances in python? Or is there a better way to have both, control over the path and a way to modify the resulting duplicates?

Comment: I don't think so, not without making them real objects. they are "duplicates", after all.