# How to customize a material without duplicating it?

Tags: python, materials, node-editor

I know how to share a material among different objects, customizing it by using the `ObjectInfo` node. I want do something similar but replacing the `ObjectInfo` node with a custom property (different for each object, and animated with an F-Curve) that the material can automatically read as input.

How could I do this? Adding a custom property to the object? How would I access it from nodes? Could the `ObjectInfo` node be enhanced to support this custom property (as well as `random`, `object index`, `location`, `material index`)?

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40634/use-custom-properties-variable-values-in-the-node-editor

Comment: What kind of property do you need? Integer, float, vector?

Comment: I need a float, in the range [0.0, 1.0]. The following answer would work, but I was hoping for an easier way (e.g. augmenting the `ObjectInfo` node with a custom property). https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72101/capture-object-properties-to-use-in-a-cycles-material

Comment: @RayMairlot That link does solve my problem using drivers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could hack the Object ID property, the maximum is 32767 so that would give you 1 / 32767 = 0.00003 precision in [0,1] range. For real floats you can use vertex colors, but that is bigger workaround. The ultimate would be to script your own cycles node, but you would have to distribute that as an addon to everywhere you want it to work. It's also a lot more work.

Comment: Are you sure that those drivers solve your problem? The driver will have the same value for every object the material is applied to. The driver lives inside the material, not on the object.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny But the driver will drive the `value` node using each object's custom property, won't it?

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny Do you have an example on how to hack the object id property? Also, two objects could end up with the same id; wouldn't that be a problem?

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny You are right about the driver not being a valid approach. I would need to duplicate the material so the value node's driver can use different objects as targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not that many options how to input unique data of each object into a shader node tree.

There are vertex colors, hacking UV coordinates as numerical input, and outputs of *Object Info* node. There is also an option of scripting a custom Cycles node.

Because you need float in range <0, 1>, using the Object Index seems feasible. It's an integer with max value of 32767, which scaled into 0-1 range gives you 1/32767 of precision (0.00003), which is not bad. This is how you'd use it inside your material:

[image]

This is the property to animate for each object:

[image]

Just multiply your value with 32767 and round it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.