# Using 'Float Property Layers' value in Node Editor (similar to Vertex Color)

Tags: node-editor, properties

I have an object called `origin` with 272 meshes/faces and `Float Property Layers` (called `random_layer`), i.e. every mesh has a its own attribute. You can see random values in the Data -> Outliner -> Data API (see screenshot).

**Goal:** I want to use the values of the `random_layer` to manipulate shaders/nodes.

**Already tried:** To get the values, I tried to use the `Attribute Node` calling it with the name `random_layer`, or `["random_layer"]`, but with no luck. I tried to wire the the three output nodes, but all seem to output 0.0. Setting the `name` to `Col` (for `Vertex Colors`) works fine.

The object has a material ('TheOne') using a `Vertex Color` node, this is working.

I have searched and found this: [Use custom properties (variable values) in the node editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40634/use-custom-properties-variable-values-in-the-node-editor) 
However, this is not actually using the values of the `Float Property Layers`, but rather the graph editor. Also, my values are static and not dynamic.

[image: NodeEditorFloatPropertyLayers]

Any help or pointers are much appreciated.

**Setup**

- Win10 Pro
- Blender 2.81a
- Engine: Cycles (also tried Eevee)
- Add-ons: 'Node Wrangler' and 'Sun Position'

**Update**
just to clarify how the float layer is created. `mesh_object` is an intermediate object for one mesh/cell/face that you see in the screenshot.

```
random_layer = mesh_object.data.polygon_layers_float.new(name="random_layer")
random_layer.data[mesh_object.data.polygons.active].value = random.uniform(0.0, 1.0)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

random_layer = bm.faces.layers.float.get(random_layer.name)
```

Also I am using the experimental 2.82a

Answer (score 2):

**Using UV Layer**

[image]
*Example showing UVMap*

Then use the UV Map node as input.

[image]
UV layers and vertex color layers are available to the attribute node by name. **Not** custom polygon float layers.  Be careful not to  name two layers of different type the same, (which you can) if you are going to use either or both as  node input.

Script that sets a float layer to randoms, then for each face sets the uv of each loop vert; u to the face layer value, and v to another random (*or ...*).

Can only have 8 UV Maps.

```
import bpy
from random import random
context = bpy.context

def get_mesh_layer(me, type, name="Float Layer"):
    layer = getattr(me, type)
    return layer.get(name) or layer.new(name=name)

#bpy.ops.object.mode_set() 
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

rflayer = get_mesh_layer(me, "polygon_layers_float")
for f in me.polygons:
    rflayer.data[f.index].value = random()

uv_layer = get_mesh_layer(me, "uv_layers", "Random")

for f in me.polygons:
    u, v = rflayer.data[f.index].value, random()
    for l in f.loop_indices:
        uv_layer.data[l].uv = u, v
#bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

*Note: needs to be run in object mode. Can be emulated in edit mode using bmesh. Simply wrapped it in change mode ops for screen shot above*

Comment: please do not delete answer, yet

Comment: I had named both "Random"... it was always using the uv layer.. double stumped myself.  Looks like the UV could be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @batFINGER. Couldn't I skip the float layer all together and assign my values to the `uv_layer` directly?

Comment: Definitely.  Added float layer only re q.

Comment: for example V in the UV Map has been set directly.  Give the UV Layer it's own name, not the name of the floatlayer (which was the cause of all my confusion lol) in code above and can ditch the float layer.