# set shader properties by mesh face index/position in ply file

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, mesh, scripting, node-editor

I'm trying to set color and other properties of a shader dependent on the specific face of an imported mesh.

To make the problem a little bit less abstract, I'll give you the background: I did physics simulations on a surface mesh with some other software and got a timeline of values for each mesh face saved somewhere in a textfile. I want to make an animation, where these values are color coded on the surface mesh with blender.

I'm not exactly a blender pro and tried to fumble around with .osl scripts to the effect that I can set the time-dependent color of an object by using something like

```
float my_array[120] = {
#include "myfile.txt"
};
```

within the .osl script. I don't know whether there is a better way, any suggestions are welcome, but it works for now.

But now I'm stuck. The script needs a second input: the specific mesh face, preferrably as the index at which it occurs in the .ply file of the mesh. If I had that, i could again load some flattened array, calculate an index in it from the mesh index and the time. But how do I get that index? The Geometry node does not have something like that and a UV-map also doesn't seem like the place to look.

Thanks in advance for any pointers

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161664/using-float-property-layers-value-in-node-editor-similar-to-vertex-color  and  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76520/how-to-get-random-color-variation-on-a-single-mesh